# Cannot update a row with a bind variable in UPDATE statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.0.13.

Query :

```
UPDATE employes 
   SET emptime = systimestamp 
 WHERE emp_id = 123 
   AND emp_device = :abc;
```

Field Definition : `emp_device char(20 byte)`

Value is : 99998000000008880999  (This value is present in the table)

When I run the above query in SQL developer it asks me to give the value for the bind variable, which I paste in the text box and it returns 0 rows updated.

But when I remove the bind variable in the update query and specify the actual value, it updates the column value.  Below is the query.

Query:

```
UPDATE employes 
   SET emptime = systimestamp 
 WHERE emp_id = 123 
   AND emp_device = 99998000000008880999 ;
```

---(works)

Also, when I add some trailing spaces in the bind variable text box and trim the emp_device column, it updates the column. Below is the query.

Query :

```
UPDATE employes 
   SET emptime = systimestamp 
 WHERE emp_id = 123 
   AND emp_device = trim(:abc);
```

-- (works --- :abc value is '99998000000008880999   ')

I do not know what is wrong with it. Can someone please take a look and suggest a solution.

Comment: What is the type of `:abc`?

Comment: I did not define any variable named :abc and SQL Developer didn't ask me to...as suppose to SQLPlus.. I tried this in SQL Developer still didnot work.  ------>                                                                                 variable abc char(21);
exec :abc :=89148001700748180966;

Answer (score 0):

You are using CHAR type for your emp_device datatype. Note that CHAR type always blank pads the resulting string out to a fixed width.[read this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476).

You should use VARCHAR2 as datatype if you are expecting a string or just NUMBER as your example consists purely of numeric values.

Comment: I altered the column to varchar2..still the same results... tried with number...still the same...

Comment: can you share your table description and the row with emp_device = 99998000000008880999

Answer (score -1):

in dialog box enter your parameter as '99998000000008880999' use apostrophe chars.

Comment: Tried.. Still didn't work.  Script output of the result :                                  0 rows updated.
:ABC                           
--------------------------------
'99998000000008880999'

Comment: please share your create table script.